# Root View Controller and unwind segues?

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7, unwind-segue, rootviewcontroller

I have 3 View Controllers:
1) LoginViewController.
2) MainViewController.
3) LogoutViewController.

I am using NSUserDefaults to store the username when he login from LoginViewController.

Then in the AppDelegate I use this method:

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let UserData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if (UserData.stringForKey("Username") != nil) {
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as! MainViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    } else {
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    }
```

So, When there is Username stored in the NSUserDefaults, the app jump to Main View Controller and skip the first at App launch.

in the LogoutViewController I used unwind segue to LoginViewController, meaning that I have a logout button and I used unwind segue to go to the LoginViewController. That works fine when the app starts from LoginViewController but not from MainViewController.

However, I want the to go to LoginViewController when Logout Button Pressed whether it starts from LoginViewController or MainViewController and release all other ViewControllers from memory. How can it be?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the LoginViewController as rootViewController on logout instead of unwinding the segue.

```
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = initialViewController
```

Comment: Do we need to dismiss the other viewControllers on the stack? I'm worried that simply replacing the rootViewController will cause a memory leak by allowing the other viewControllers to exist

Comment: No you don't need to dismiss other viewControllers. Setting RootViewController will reset the stack.

Answer (score 0):

In your case LoginViewController as root view is called first when app is launched. So when you log-out, you should pop to root view controller